# Proving that $a_n \to 0$ is a necessary condition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to understand an excerpt from my GRE preparation notes.

> If $\left(a_{n}\right)$ is a non-negative sequence decreasing to zero, and $\left(b_{n}\right)$ is any series whose partial sums are bounded, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{n}$ converges. The alternating series test is the case where $b_n = (-1)^n$. We can prove by example that the assumption that $\left(a_{n}\right)$ is decreasing is necessary. Without this, the alternating series could diverge even if $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$.

I've been trying to construct such a counterexample, but I haven't been successful. Could anyone help with this? My idea was to try to use the harmonic series to somehow construct an example where $a_n \to 0$ but $a_n$ wasn't a decreasing sequence (which may give the desired counterexample for $b_n = (-1)^n$), but I was going nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to take $\{a_n\}$ to the harmonic sequence with some zeros in between. In particular, $a_{2n}=\frac 1{n}$ and $a_k=0$ if $k\neq 2n$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$.

Now, take $\{b_n\}$ to be the sequence $\{(-1)^n\}$. Note that $b_{2n}=1$ as $2n$ is always even. So,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$$
which diverges.

Comment: What should $b_n$ be for this counterexample to work?

Comment: @Clarent I messed up a little lasrt time. But, now I edited it. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Clarent But, $a_n$ was of course going to zero. It still is.